# Mysql -- Last 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table with two colums.

- The first column is a date stored as: (example): `01/01/2015 00:00:00`
- The seconds column is a number : as (example) : 500

I have written an SQL Statement which looks like this:

```
select * 
from cc_open_incident_view
WHERE (DATE =(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

If I execute this statement it doesn't retrieve any data and I can't find the mistake

I want only the data for the last month as a result of the query (last 30 days).

Would appreciate any help..

Edit as per OP comments:

Date is saved as date and it's working, but the column date in my table has stored the dates for the next 5 years and it shows the data like: `09.03.2016` (which is tomorrow) too. Is there any way to only show the date from `30 days` back till `today`?

Comment: Store dates as `date`s rather than strings, and you will fix this . . . and other . . . problems.

Comment: Two things.  1) make sure the date you are passing in is actually a date, you can convert to date in SQL if needed.  2) Now() is returning a time in addition to the date, and you are comparing the entire datetime for equality.  This means the time has to match as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Forgot that the time will be compared too. =)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit: Changed query as per OP

```
select * 
from cc_open_incident_view
WHERE date between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE()
```

Previous Answer:

If date is saved as `date` then use this

```
select * 
from cc_open_incident_view
WHERE date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

If date is saved as string then use this (assuming it is in `dd/mm/yyyy ...`

```
select * 
from cc_open_incident_view
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date ,''%d/%m/%y %h:%i:%s')>= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

Comment: Date is saved as date and it's working, but the column date in my table has stored the dates for the next 5 years and it shows the data like: 09.03.2016 (which is tommorow) too.. Is there any way to only show the date from today  - 30 days back?

Comment: Check the updated answer. If it works for you then accept the answer so it could be closed.

Comment: Working, Thank you =)

Comment: If date is saved as string, fix data.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    cc_open_incident_view
WHERE   yourdatetimecolumn BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Also note that `CURDATE()` returns only the `DATE` portion of the date, so if you store `yourdatetimecolumn` as a `DATETIME` with the time portion filled, this query will not select the today's records.

In this case, you'll need to use `NOW` instead:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    cc_open_incident_view
WHERE   yourdatetimecolumn BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype is datetime or timestamp (and you want to check the time):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE yourdatetimeortimestampcolumn <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

If your column datatype is date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE yourdatecolumn <= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

If your column is a string, you will need to convert it first by doing:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from cc_open_incident_view where DATE >= [strat date] and DATE <= [current date];
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, and thanks for your answer. Please try to provide some explanation to code-only answers.