# PHP sql query, select all where date is less than 60 days from today

Tags: php, sql

When I use the following code nothing pops up, when I take away the date_sub stuff and don't try to search by date it gets the data.

```
$quotes = $crmdb->query("
           SELECT q
           FROM quotes q
           WHERE q.display = '1'
           AND q.shipped_date < ".date_sub(date("Y/m/d"),-60)."   //NEEDS FIXED
       ");
```

Basically I want the items that have been shipped in the last 60 days from today. I know similar questions have been asked but I browsed those and the code is not working for me, so I am asking my question! Thanks.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: For mysql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868634/mysql-last-30-days/35868812

Comment: don't concat your queries. **parameterise** them. will solve a bunch of problems, probably this included, and secure your database from **SQL injection attacks**

Comment: @ChrisWhite I believe it is MySQLI

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is it seriously *that* vulnerable from injection attacks from being left alone like this? I thought SQLI's purpose was to be less vulnerable.

Comment: @user3783243 that worked I believe.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I believe it only applies to where user input can be made and put into the query? No?

Comment: it's simple, there is **no** reason ever **not** to use parameterised statements. make a habit out of it, so you don't forget it at other places. *and* reap the benefits of far less bugs and better performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql -- Last 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868634/mysql-last-30-days)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using mysql  Try using  `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)`

```
SELECT q
FROM quotes q
WHERE q.display = '1'
AND q.shipped_date  < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem here you are trying to select the `q` but you use it as an alias of quotes
try to this.

```
 $quotes = $crmdb->query("
               SELECT *
               FROM quotes q
               WHERE q.display = '1'
               AND q.shipped_date < ".date_sub(date("Y/m/d"),-60)." 
           ");
```

or

```
$quotes = $crmdb->query("
           SELECT column1, colum2
           FROM quotes q
           WHERE q.display = '1'
           AND q.shipped_date < ".date_sub(date("Y/m/d"),-60)."  
       ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: i hope it will  work for you.

```
SELECT  quotes q
FROM    quotes
WHERE q.display = '1'
WHERE   shipped_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY AND CURDATE()
```