# Select * from database table for the last 30 days doesnt return all elements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For Android, the date is saved like this `Fri Apr 12 10:16:01 EDT 2019` and on iOs, its saved like this `2019-10-16 00:27:12  0000`.

The problem is, when I query the DB

```
SELECT *
FROM appsearch
WHERE username = '$userID' and
       date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 200 DAY
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It wont pick up the items from the Android search, only IOS. How can I pull both? I know fixing the API would be best, but im past that.

Comment: Your select has no date that it uses so **i didn't get your question**. And i am pretty sure that mysql gives you an error with this select as long as you don't use bachticks for your column date. and last i hope you use prepared statements.

Comment: You can follow thos article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868634/mysql-last-30-days/35868812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Android dates are not in a form which can be compared to a MySQL DATE, you must convert them first. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for this, using `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to cut out the day, month and year parts of the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM appsearch
WHERE username = 1 AND
      (DATE(date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 200 DAY OR
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(date, 10), RIGHT(date, 4)), '%a %b %e %Y') >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 200 DAY
       )
ORDER BY COALESCE(DATE(date), STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(date, 10), RIGHT(date, 4)), '%a %b %e %Y')) DESC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f397c1f3f7edb2a69292b9b56b90e5d5)

**Note**

1. We cut out the middle part of the time string since I presume the timezone is not constant, and `STR_TO_DATE` requires that literal characters in the format string match exactly, so you would otherwise require multiple different format strings (e.g. for `EDT`, `PST`, etc.) to convert all of them.
2. You need to change the `ORDER BY` clause to use the `date` value that was being used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: if I wanted to do this but lets say pick a specific date range. For example, from January 1 2019 to January 14 2019. How would I edit this?

Comment: @soldfor you could replace `>= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 200 DAY` with `BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-14'`